# Celery worker receiving too many tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have started my Celery worker like this:

```
celery -A workerTasks worker --concurrency 1 --loglevel=info
```

But i see that it is receiving multiple tasks:

```
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,371: INFO/MainProcess] celery@2aaf46abfaed ready.
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,372: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workerTasks.do_processing_task[a3c19e7a-6b04-4236-8afc-0884547d3f39]  
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,373: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workerTasks.do_processing_task[f22443c1-6dee-4ecf-8c54-7a7c4da5418e]  
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,373: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workerTasks.do_processing_task[6eb501b7-c192-46db-be78-6061300b6bdf]  
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,373: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workerTasks.do_processing_task[ec08b59f-541e-42fc-806d-cfbd40daf7b7]  
[2019-05-08 10:33:07,479: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workerTasks.do_processing_task[deaaec17-b07c-4476-9b44-9f8e884b0b6e]
```

Why is it not just receiving one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this due to the `worker_prefetch_multiplier` setting. From the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-prefetch-multiplier):

> How many messages to prefetch at a time multiplied by the number of
>   concurrent processes. The default is 4 (four messages for each
>   process). The default setting is usually a good choice, however – if
>   you have very long running tasks waiting in the queue and you have to
>   start the workers, note that the first worker to start will receive
>   four times the number of messages initially. Thus the tasks may not be
>   fairly distributed to the workers.

Basically, Celery will try to fetch tasks in batches from your broker. This is done in order to avoid too many round trips.

Comment: I'm setting
```app.conf['worker_prefetch_multiplier'] = 1```
and still getting five jobs received, so something else is going on..

Comment: Are you sure that the configuration really applied? Are the tasks actually being executed in parallel? Put some print statement in the beginning and end if not sure.